# What kind of advantages does GeoPtProperty have?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I think I could also store latitude/longitude data in FloatProperty or ListProperty.

Comment: I think it's a more important question than it may look at first. You're basically asking why use an ADT (abstract data type) when a primitive seems to work for the same purpose. We asked "what does this type do?" since 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With google's API you will be able to make [location-based searches](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/overview#Performing_Location-Based_Searches). You can also use the geoproperty in templates with float formatting ("2" in this case will be number of decimals):

`<georss:point>{{entity.geopt.lon|floatformat:2}},{{entity.geopt.lat|floatformat:2}}</georss:point>`

You can also look at the [geomodel project](https://code.google.com/p/geomodel/) which I think is being superseeded by the google search api enabling location-based searches if you make an index.

Answer (score 5):

I think for now it just makes sure that the latitude and longitude values are correct, while if you have your own `FloatProperty` they can have any arbitrary values that are not necessarily coordinates. Other than that I don't think that you will have any other benefit.

Also, while Google is not supporting spatial search out of the box, maybe in the future they will and if they will they will use this property for that.